# PyQGIS zoom using PyQt list widget

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, pyqt

I have created a layer filter Expression to get specific results query
from my layer and I add these results in a list widget using PyQt.

My Expression and my add to list widget work fine (I print correct ids and I see those ids in list widget).

However, if I want to zoom to a feature using double click signal in the list widget then it zooms to the wrong features (features where my Expression is False). Any idea what I have wrong in my code?

My code:

```py
__init__ 
self.connect(self.ui.listWidget, SIGNAL("itemDoubleClicked (QListWidgetItem 
*)"), self.Zoomt)
```

My filter:

```py
def myfilter(self): 
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("mylayrt")[0] 
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('"name" =\'{0}\''.format(myname)) 
    for feature in layer.getFeatures(request): 
        print str(feature.attribute("myid")) 
        self.ui.listWidget.addItem(str(feature.attribute("myid")))
```

Result print:

```
1 
42 
43 
44 
45 
96 
111 
304 
458 
508 
579 
602 
606 
646
```

That is ids are added correctly in the list widget (14 ids).

Zoom button:

```py
def Zoomt(self): 
    Vl_Gs = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("mylayer")[0] 
    Vl_Gs.removeSelection 
    Vl_Gs.setSelectedFeatures([self.ui.listWidget.currentRow()]) 
    self.mapCanvas.zoomToSelected(Vl_Gs)
```

Zoom ids (take first 14 from my layer):

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 
11 
12 
13
```

Ids len number is correct but the ids zoom is wrong, why?

Comment: I think `Vl_Gs.removeSelection` should be `Vl_Gs.removeSelection()`

Comment: @Joseph i change this code line but i have some problem,any other idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting selected features, you will need the **id** of those features. You're using `Vl_Gs.setSelectedFeatures([self.ui.listWidget.currentRow()])` which only gets the index value of the listwidget row. What you could do is create another feature request and match the feature's attribute with the selected item. Maybe something like:

```
def Zoomt(self): 
    Vl_Gs = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("mylayer")[0] 
    expr = QgsExpression('"name" =\'{0}\''.format(self.ui.listWidget.currentItem().text()))
    selection = Vl_Gs.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
    ids = [s.id() for s in selection]
    Vl_Gs.selectByIds(ids)
    self.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected(Vl_Gs)
```

---

*Note that the method [QgsVectorLayer::setSelectedFeatures()](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a4d82285142c108ba73622ce53207759c) has been depreciated in 2.18 and you should instead use [QgsVectorLayer::selectByIds()](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a927ae6e3e40ff37ed2a0d104fe6ff242).*

---

**Edit:**

If using QGIS < 2.16, use `setSelectedFeatures()` (which you have originally used) so replace the following line:

```
Vl_Gs.selectByIds(ids)
```

with

```
Vl_Gs.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
```

Comment: you are correct about id,now if i print `self.ui.listWidget.currentItem().text()` then i take correct feature id..but not work your code i take error : AttributeError:`QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'selectByIds`, any idea where i have wrong ?i use QGIS 2.14

Comment: i think so `selectByIds()` not exist in QGIS 2.14

Comment: @hellas - Yes you are correct, `selectByIds()` is only availablel from QGIS 2.16 onwards. Stick with your original line: `setSelectedFeatures(ids)` :)

Comment: all work fine now,but i have one question about `zoot` function.why use `expr = QgsExpression('"name" =\'{0}\''.format(self.ui.listWidget.currentItem().text()))` again because if i print `self.ui.listWidget.currentItem().text()` then i take correct id

Comment: @hellas - It was just to ensure you get the correct value from the list widget. You could modify your code so that you only need to use that line once :)